# How to count text, but not hidden cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Can someone tell me how I can count text in a column, but exclude the hidden rows? I just want a tally of cells containing text. Please help!?

Comment: Have a look here: https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/AGGREGATE-function-c8caed56-07df-4aeb-9741-23693ffbe525

Answer (score 0):

`=SUBTOTALS()` for LibreOffice always consider hidden cells in Autofilter

Excel on the other hand has special function indexes for that, those that are numbered 100 and above.

Look for `COUNTA` in the help for the SUSBTOTAL function.